# String Variable Character Limit

Tags: c#, string, variables

My String variable only stores 4096 characters, I need to store more, how can i achieve that?

Below is what i am trying to do

```
ServiceController[] myServices = ServiceController.GetServices();
String ServiceList = "";

foreach (ServiceController service in myServices)
{

      ServiceList += service.DisplayName + "|||";

} 
return ServiceList;
```

When the variable is returned, it only stores 4096 characters and rest are trimmed off.

P.S. I need them in one variable as I am making a URL out of them and passing to my webservice.

Comment: .Net strings have a maximum length of 2^31 code points, not 2^12.

Comment: You could use a StringBuilder rather than a simple string, but I strongle recommend you to read the answers and think on a new solution. URLs should be as short as possible.

Comment: So why is it storing just 2^12 characters?

Comment: It's not, @Uzair. Strings can store much, *much* more than that. Are you sure that's just not the natural length of the data you're storing in that string? What is the value of `ServiceList.Length` at the end of the method above?

Comment: At what point in the code did you measure the length of the string?

Answer (score 4):

> I need them in one variable as I am making a URL out of them and passing to my webservice.

No, don't do that!

A 4096 character URL is a very bad idea and is not guaranteed to work.

> Extremely long URLs are usually a mistake. URLs over 2,000 characters will not work in the most popular web browser. Don't use them if you intend your site to work for the majority of Internet users.

[(source)](http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/misc/urllength.html)

Make a shortened URL that contains an id. Store the rest of the information in a database with the short id as the key.

**Related**

- [What is the maximum length of a URL in different browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url)
- [Maximum URL length is 2,083 characters in Internet Explorer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208427)

Comment: actually i am just calling a webpage from within my code and passing this variable as a parameter. That webpage only explodes the string and inserts into database. I have no other option as the windows service dont have access to the database. I need to go this path...

Comment: @UzairShahid: .NET strings do not have a maximum length of 4096 characters. You are looking for the error in the wrong place.

Answer (score 3):

.NET string length limit is 2 billion characters.

Browsers do have a limit on how long of a URL they will accept, and the length limit is different across browser implementations.  IE's limit is typically the shortest, at around 2k last time I checked in the IE6 era.  Firefox and Chrome are considerably higher than that, but there is still a limit.

Comment: Thanks for that, but why my variable only stores 4096 characters??

Comment: How are you observing that the string only contains 4096 characters?  are you inspecting the variable in a debugger before the function returns? Or are you looking at some web result after your value has been through dozens of system layers?

Answer (score 0):

Strings in C# has about 2Gig limit.so there is no problem with your string variable

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is elsewhere - but it is not possible to reliably use a URL that uses more than 2000 characters, you will need another approach entirely - see this SO answer: [What is the maximum length of a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/417184/329769)

(Also for building large strings use a `StringBuilder` instead)